# mailtoリンクがAndroidで動作しない

Tags: android, ios, monaca

お世話になります。

monaca(OnsenUI）を使用してアプリ開発をしています。
初歩的な質問になるかもしれませんが、
Ipad(iphone)では

```
    <a href="mailto:">test</a>
```

をクリックするとメーラーが起動しますが、
androidでは起動しません（バージョン4.2.2で確認）

なぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

WebViewもしくはCordovaの仕様ですね。
WebIntentプラグインは利用できないでしょうか。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_plugin/webintent/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181077/how-to-send-email-with-webintent-plugin-monaca-ide

Comment: ありがとうございます。webintentプラグインを使ってできました。助かりました。

こういう場合はメール送信ボタンをios用とandroid用に２つ作るのか、そもそもプログラムを分けるべきなのか、どちらが良いのでしょうか。

Comment: if(monaca.isIOS)かif(monaca.isAndroid)で比較しましょう

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。お礼が遅くなりすみませんでした。